# Connectedness property of $R^2$

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis, graph-theory, algebraic-topology, connectedness

My class teacher proposed this problem which seem very interesting.

> If we remove countably many open disc from $R^2$. Is the remaining 
>    space still be path connected.

I have done the problem for the case when disc are not disjoint and find out that space need not be path connected.
But I am wondering what happen if disc are 
 disjoint.my guess is space should be path connected any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I would try to show path connectivity by constructing a series of line segments joining two points that are successively made to avoid all disks above a certain radius. Then I would try to argue that these converge to a path in the limit. I don't know if this actually works but it is my best idea at the moment.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip,thanks for sharing your idea.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip: This should work if the closures of the discs are disjoint but I'm a little worried about doing this in the case where they're not.

Comment: Well if we have a map $j:\bigcup_i D^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$, then by thickening slightly around each map, $\mathbb{R}^2-im(j)$ can be modified to a homotopy equivalent space, $X$, such that $im(j)$ and $X$ form an cover. Then we have a reduced Mayer-Vietoris sequence, $0\to H_0(X\cap im(j))\to H_0(X)\oplus H_0(im(j))\to 0$. But we have that $H_0(X\cap im(j))\to H_0(X)$ is an isomorphism, looking at the map induced by $D^2\to S^1$ given by contracting to a point, which is an isomorphism on path-components. Thus we must have that $H_0(im(j))=0$ as desired, if I have not made a stupid mistake.

Comment: @chanler,thanks for your post but I am not familiar with all these terminology but iI am sure there is some elementary way .

Comment: @Chanler: the thickening you are talking about is not obviously a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: You write that your guess is that the space should be connected. I presume you mean "path-connected" again there?

Comment: @joriki,yes i mean to be path connected.

Comment: If I can replace discs by open rectangles, then I can construct some counter example....

Comment: @Anubhav.K,That would be nice.pls share.

Comment: @Anubhav.K: That would imply that the proof in my answer is flawed, since it should also work for open rectangles.

Comment: @joriki I've posted one counter example for rctangles, just check it, and tell me whether it is correct or not.

Comment: @joriki: I don't think your proof works for open rectangles because you may need to distort a very short segment by quite a long amount.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip: You're quite right; for some reason I was thinking of squares instead of rectangles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The set is path-connected. Given $A$ and $B$, construct a path from $A$ to $B$ by starting with the straight line segment from $A$ to $B$, with uniform speed; whereever this is in the space, the path is given by the line segment; wherever it is not, this is because of a specific disk; define the path to map the interval that would have been mapped to a chord of this disk to the corresponding minor arc with constant speed (where if the line segment cuts the disk in half, choose, say, the left-hand arc). The arc is covered neither by this disk, nor by any other disjoint disk. Continuity follows from the fact that the remapping cannot stretch distances along the path by more than a factor of $\pi/2$.

Comment: I like this. So simple!

Comment: @joriki,Thanks.

Comment: @joriki,is there something specific about minor arc can i instead use major    arc

Comment: @joriki,sorry i did't understood which continuity you talking about.

Comment: Nice answer!${}$

Comment: @MichaelKotelskiy: I'm not sure whether your second comment is a second question or an indication that your first question was resolved. In any case, I'm not sure you can carry the proof through with the major arcs; at least it would be more complicated; the stretching factor isn't bounded from above in that case (like in the case of open rectangles), so you'd need a more complicated argument for continuity. To answer your second comment (in case it was a question): The continuity I'm talking about is the continuity of the map defining the path (which must be continuous for it to be a path).

Comment: @joriki,I am wondering where have you use the fact that we are removing countably many open disc or is that your proof is valid still in case for removing of uncountably many disc.

Comment: and thanks for your explanation of my two questions.

Comment: @MichaelKotelskiy: That's a very good question, which led me to see a flaw in the proof. I've edited the answer accordingly; will try to get back to it as soon as I can.

Comment: @joriki,Thanks.

Comment: I don't see what the flaw is. You are removing disjoint disks. The boundaries of the disks may touch, but that's okay, the construction actually fixes the two endpoints where the arc meets each disk initially.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip: You're absolutely right. Somehow in thinking about Michael's question about removing uncountably many discs (and trying to prove that you can't) I lost track of the fact that the disks are disjoint :-). I've removed the note.

Comment: @MichaelKotelskiy: It's actually impossible to remove uncountably many disjoint discs from $\mathbb R^2$. Consider the unit square -- if you can count the disks overlapping this square, you can do it in all squares, and thus in $\mathbb R^2$. First count all disks that cover at least an area $1/2$ in the square, then those of the remaining ones that cover at least $1/3, 1/4, \ldots$. In each step there's a finite number of disks, and you reach all of them eventually.

Comment: Another proof that you can's remove uncountably many open balls from $\mathbb R^2$: pick an ordered pair of rationals in each ball. That gives an injection from the set of balls to $\mathbb Q^2$.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip: (Nice name by the way -- I only now realized that it's English :-) That's also a nice proof. It's perhaps worth noting that you can order the ordered pairs of rationals (since you can count them) and pick the "least" pair, so you don't need choice for this proof.

Comment: @joriki,are you are saying even if we remove uncountably many  open disc space would remains path connected.

Comment: @MichaelKotelskiy: No, that's not what I'm saying. I'm saying that it's impossible to remove uncountably many disjoint open discs from $\mathbb R^2$. Both my proof and the grumpy parsnip's proof prove this.

Comment: @joriki,I got it thanks both of you for having such a nice discussion.

Comment: @joriki,can i think of it in the same way i can not move out uncounlably many disjoint open interval in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @MichaelKotelskiy: Yes, exactly.

Comment: @joriki: You have claimed that this proof is flawed. Why are you not concerned any more that there is maybe no first ball you encounter on the way from $A$ to $B$? How would you modify the path in that situation?

Comment: @user251257: Please see my exchange of comments with GrumpyParsnip above. I was merely temporarily confused when I thought the proof was flawed. There's no need for a first ball to be encountered on the way from $A$ to $B$, and no need to modify the path if there's no first ball. The path is well-defined by the construction in my answer; I just briefly thought that it wasn't because I'd temporarily forgotten that the disks are disjoint.

Comment: @joriki: Ah, I get the idea. Thx.

Answer (score 6):

This might be a counter example where I replace open balls by open rectangles.

let consider the set {$1/n$}... if $n$ is odd  thne consider the open  rectangles $(1/n,1/n+1) \times (2k, 2k+2)$ s.t $ k \in \mathbb{Z}$ ...and if $n$ is even then consider open rectangles  $ (1/n,1/n+1) \times (2k+1, 2k+3)$ s.t $ k \in \mathbb{Z}$... now my claim is that if I take out all such rectangles from $\mathbb{R^2}$ , then the remaining space cannot be be path connectedto prove this we can use some similar kind of argement which we usually do while proving that topological sine curve is not path-connected...

Comment: thaks for your effort.I will go into its detail.

Comment: Nice!${\phantom{.}}$

Comment: Why do you say you're not sure whether this can be done for open balls or not? Do you think there's a flaw in the proof in my answer?

Comment: @joriki your answer is fine to me, let me just edit mine ...